# Thread bad access

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

It is working until I try to print the value in the third node (the one with value 3)
Its giving me a bad access error (code = 1 address = 0x0) on the getNext() function definition line.
What is the problem? Why does it work for the first two, but then not?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ListNode {
    float val;
    ListNode *next;

public:
    ListNode(){val = 0;}
    ListNode(float f){val =f;next = NULL;}

    void setNext(ListNode *node){next = node;}

    void setVal(float f){val = f;}

    float getVal(){return val;}

    ListNode getNext(){return *next;}
};

int main()
{
    ListNode n = *new ListNode(5);
    n.setNext(new ListNode(9));
    n.getNext().setNext(new ListNode(3));

    cout << n.getVal() <<endl;
    n = n.getNext();

    cout << n.getVal() <<endl;
    n = n.getNext();
    cout << n.getVal() <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `*new` instead of `ListNode n(5)`? You're leaking memory all over the place here, nothing is released.

Comment: tadman, I changed the first one to that, but it does not work for the others.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is here:

```
ListNode getNext(){return *next;}
```

It returns a COPY of your node by value. When you call `setNext()` on that value, you're just modifying a temporary instance which is destroyed at the end of the expression. So it has no lasting effect.

An alternative would be this:

```
ListNode& getNext(){return *next;}
```

This will return a *reference* to the node. I believe this will fix the problem you're asking about. You have others, such as leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.
Is the memory leaking just from the new on the first node? Xcode would not allow me to change the others away from new ListNode(9).